# I found an XSS site while searching

Tags: xss, disclosure

I found a site where XSS is running
I want to report this site because it is dangerous for others
Where should I report it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can report to Computer Emergency Response Team or Incident Response Team of respective jurisdiction.

Comment: In that country?
Or in the country of XSS site?

Comment: Ofcourse.. In that country where your computer is connected to your internet service provider is located. Because sometimes you may not be successful finding XSS site's country of origin.

Comment: I would first try to contact the owner / technical team of the website rather than directly reporting it to the authority.